Android Custom Gradle Plugin significantly increases size of app
I have a local custom cradle plugin made in the form of a class that inherits Plugin.
But when I connect to the project, the size of the application increases very much +30 MB.
class CustomAndroidPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.tasks.whenTaskAdded{ task ->
            if (task.name in listOf("1", "2")){

            }
        }
    }
}

If I connect exactly the same plugin, then my size will increase by 20-30 MB.
What could this be related to?
P.S.
The plugin is located in the buildSrc module and is connected in the main application module
If you remove whenTaskAdded, the size does not increase as if the plugin is not connected.
class CustomAndroidPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {}
}

Also, when my logic is present in this plugin, the size is the same and remains +30MB (does not increase additionally)

"then my size will increase by 20-30 MB" - the size of what exactly? The resulting built APK file? The amount of dependencies to be downloaded when your Gradle project is synced? The outputted build intermediate files? We'll also need additional information as to what the plugin does exactly, as your question is not really reproducible, see [mcve]
